# Desrcibing all the equivalent martingale measures (EMM)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, finance

**Exercise :**

> Consider the finite sample space $\Omega = \{\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3\}$ and the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb P)$ with $\mathcal F:= 2^\Omega$ and let $\mathbb P$ be a probability measure such that $\mathbb P[\{\omega_1\}] > 0$ for all $i=1,2,3$ .
>
> Let :
>   $$\bar{S}_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\2\\7 \end{pmatrix}, \quad\bar{S}_1(\omega_1) = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\3\\9\end{pmatrix}, \quad \bar{S}_1(\omega_2) = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\5\end{pmatrix}, \quad \bar{S}_1(\omega_3) = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\13\\10 \end{pmatrix}$$
>   Describe all the equivalent martingale measures.

**Definitions and request for help/elaboration :**

> **Theorem :** Let $\mathbb P, \mathbb Q$ be two probability measures  over the space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$. Then, it is $\mathbb P \sim \mathbb Q$ if and only if there exists a random variable $X>0, \; X \in L^1(\mathbb P)$ such that :
>   $$\mathbb E_\mathbb Q[\mathbf{1}_A] = \mathbb Q(A) = \int_AX\mathrm{d}\mathbb P=\mathbb E_\mathbb P[X\mathbf{1}_A], \quad \forall A \in \mathcal F$$
>
> **Definition :** A probability measure $\mathbb Q$ over the space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ is called a **martingale measure** (MM) if it is :
>   $$S_1 \in L^1(\mathbb Q) \quad \text{and} \quad S_0 = \mathbb{E}_\mathbb Q\bigg[\frac{S_1}{1+r}\bigg]$$
>
> **Definition :** If $\mathbb Q$ is a martingale measure and it also is $\mathbb Q \sim \mathbb P$, then $\mathbb Q$ is called an **equivalent martingale measure** (EMM).
>
> **Definition :** We define $\mathcal{P}$ to be the set of **all the equivalent martingale measures :**
>   $$\mathcal{P} = \{\mathbb Q|\mathbb Q \sim \mathbb P, \mathbb Q  \; \text{is an equivalent martingale measure}\}$$

**Question :** Now, given these definitions, what is needed for me to carry out so I can answer properly to the exercise given ? What am I expected to do and how ? I would really appreciate a thorough elaboration as I haven't been properly introduced to martingales and measure theory yet (there are just tools needed for a higher-level class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fact that the first asset does not change value, we can infer that the interest rate is zero. The problem is to find all probability measures $Q$ such that $$  S_0 = S_1Q(\omega_1) + S_2Q(\omega_2) +S_3Q(\omega_3),$$ and all of the three probabilities are greater than zero (and add up to one, of course). The equation expresses the fact that it is a martingale measure (the RHS is the expected discounted value). It needs all probabilities greater than zero in order to be equivalent to $P.$

As far as I can tell, there aren’t any (I find one probability measure that has the right expected value but it doesn’t have all probabilities nonzero.)

**Edit**

Going to expand on equivalence a bit. Two measures are [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_(measure_theory)) if they have the same null events. I notice the part on equivalence is marked as a theorem, not a definition, so I suspect perhaps you were given this definition at at some point. Since the physical measure $P$ you've been given has $P(\omega)>0$ for all $\omega\in\Omega,$ the only null event is the empty set. Thus for $Q$ to be equivalent, it must also have the only null event be the emptyset, i.e. $Q(\omega)>0$ for all $\omega\in \Omega.$

To see this is equivalent to the theorem that there exists a random variable $X>0$ such that for any event $A$ $$ E_Q(1_A) = E_P(X1_A),$$ as I mentioned in the comments, just take $X(\omega) = \frac{Q(\omega)}{P(\omega)},$ for all $\omega$ such that $P(\omega) >0,$ and let it be defined as any positive number elsewhere. We see that the fact that P and Q are equivalent implies $X>0$. And we have (specializing to the sample space in the problem for clarity) $$ E_Q(1_A) = 1_A(\omega_1)Q(\omega_1) + 1_A(\omega_2)Q(\omega_2) + 1_A(\omega_3)Q(\omega_3) \\=1_A(\omega_1)X(\omega_1)P(\omega_1) + 1_A(\omega_2)X(\omega_2)P(\omega_2) + 1_A(\omega_3)X(\omega_3)P(\omega_3)\\=E_P(1_A X)  $$ where we used equivalence again to deal with the possibility that $P(\omega_i) = 0$ for some $i$.

In the reverse direction, for any $X>0$, if there is an $A$ such that $Q(A) =0$ but $P(A)\ne 0,$ or vice versa then it's clear that $E_Q(1_A) \ne E_P(X 1_A)$ since one side is zero and the other isn't $(E_Q(1_A) = Q(A)$ and $E_P(X1_A) = 0$ if and only if $P(A) = 0$ since $X>0.$)

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for your answer ! How did you yield that the problem described comes down to finding all the probability measures $\mathbb Q$ such that :
$$S_0 = S_1\mathbb{Q}(\omega_1) + S_2\mathbb{Q}(\omega_2) +S_3\mathbb{Q}(\omega_3)$$ After that, I didn't really understand what you meant about the equivalence to $P$ ? Given on your hints, how would I derive a complete solution to the problem ? It's the first time I'm handling such a task, that's why I am mind boggled.

Comment: It is just the expression that the expected value is the same as the starting value for all three assets (which is what martingale means). They say all three probabilities are greater than zero in measure P, so by the definition of equivalence they must be greater than zero in Q as well.

Comment: Nicely explained ! One last question, from the definition of equivalence posted above, how does one derive that the probabilities must follow the same order of $\geq 0$ from $\mathbb P$ to $\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: I don’t understand. there’s nothing about order, or $\ge 0.$ They just all need to be greater than zero.

Comment: Yes but what about the equivalence part? This is what I don't get.

Comment: The equivalence is defined by the definition above with this weird integral. How are we working over every equivalent martingale measure after your initial elaboration?

Comment: Equivalence means the two measures agree which events have measure zero and one. Will edit my answer to square that up with the definition when I have more time later.

Comment: The short answer is you take $X(\omega)=Q(\omega)/P(\omega).$